# Django foreign key queryset forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an order form with several items available for purchase. These items (annuals, issues and articles) are attached to a Catalog object with a foreign key. I'd like to change the queryset in the form model to display the attached items instead of the Catalog name. I'm fairly new to Django, is there a way to construct this type of queryset in the form? I have added my model with the default querysets of all for each.

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit
from subscriber.models import Catalog

from . import models

class OrderListForm(forms.ModelForm):


p = Catalog.objects.get()
annuals = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Catalog.objects.all())
issues = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Catalog.objects.all())
articles = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Catalog.objects.all())

class Meta:
    fields = (
                'annuals',
                'issues',
                'articles',)
    model = models.Order


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'annuals',
                'issues',
                'articles',
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('create', 'Create')

        )


    )
```

Here is my model:

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
products = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.products

class Issue(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='issue_products')
    Volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.catalog)


class Annual(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='annual_products')
    year_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.year_id)


class Annual_Issue(models.Model):
    annual_id = models.ForeignKey(Annual, related_name='annual_ids')
    issue_id = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='issues')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.annual_id


class Article(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='article_products')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    abstract = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    full_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    proquest_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ebsco_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='who_ordered')
    order_lines = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='items_ordered')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ModelChoiceFields you have declared in your form are each using an incorrect queryset parameter. In the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), you can see that the queryset given to the ModelChoiceForm should be a queryset from which the choices within the field will be populated:

> A QuerySet of model objects from which the choices for the field will be derived, and which will be used to validate the user’s selection.

In your example, you have declared the wrong end of the foreign-key relationship to be the queryset for each ModelChoiceField. If you were to change each of the ModelChoiceFields to instead populate using the objects from the opposite end of each foreign-key relationship, you will see the ModelChoiceFields in your form now include the annuals, issues, and articles.

Here is an example using the correct queryset for each field.

```
annuals = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Annual.objects.all())
issues = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Issue.objects.all())
articles = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.all())
```

It is important to note from the documentation that ModelChoiceField will only allow a single object from each queryset to be selected within the given form. If you wish to allow the user to select multiple objects from each queryset, then you may wish to use the [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) instead.

Furthermore, you may take note from the documentation that the default value to be displayed within the choice field for each object in the queryset will be the primary-key. If you wish to display a different field value for each object within the choices of the choice selection widget, you should use a second optional parameter for the ModelChoiceField, to_field_name. This refers to the field from the Model which will be displayed within the choice selector.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the explanation as well. For some reason on submit, this error came up Cannot assign "<Annual: 2012>": "Order.annuals" must be a "Catalog" instance.

Comment: Have you changed the definition of the Order model since your original question?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think it has to do with a string being passed instead of the actual PK relationship. This is all fairly new to me so that's my best guess

Comment: To be clear, the original poster of this question followed-up this question with a second question about this comment stream, [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580192/cannot-assign-must-be-a-instance-django/26580676#26580676).